# Trying to implement a small version of std::tie and std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, std, stdtuple

So as the title says I'm trying to implement a small version of `std::tie` and `std::tuple` for learning purposes.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Tuple
{
public:
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

    template<typename Tr1, typename Tr2>
    Tuple(Tr1 tr1, Tr2 tr2) : t1(tr1), t2(tr2)
    {
    }

    template<typename Tr1, typename Tr2>
    Tuple<T1, T2>& operator =(const Tuple<Tr1, Tr2>& other)
    {
        t1 = other.t1;
        t2 = other.t2;
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
Tuple<T1&, T2&> Tie(T1& t1, T2& t2)
{
    return Tuple<T1&, T2&>(t1, t2);
}

Tuple<int, int> f()
{
    return Tuple<int, int>(3, 5);
}

int main()
{
    int hi, bye;

    Tie(hi, bye) = f();

    cout << hi << " " << bye << '\n';
}
```

It's almost working (or at least I think it is).
I debug to see that

- The Tuple(3, 5) is instantiated successfuly. then,
- The Tuple (which references hi and bye) is instantiated successfuly.
- And then lastly the assignment operator is called and the latter is assigned to the former, that is the references are assigned the 3 and the 5.

But once the `operator=` returns, `hi` and `bye` would just have their uninitialized values :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mistake is that `operator=` returns by value, whereas it should return by reference. But this is not the cause.

The cause is that a constructor from `T1` and `T2` is missing, which causes it to form references to value arguments. Fix:

```
template<typename Tr1, typename Tr2>
Tuple(Tr1&& tr1, Tr2&& tr2) 
    : t1(std::forward<Tr1>(tr1))
    , t2(std::forward<Tr2>(tr2))
{}
```

Comment: That is true. However that is not the reason why the output of the program is incorrect since the returned value is not used anywhere anyway.